# Is there a workaround for non working auth in Teams bot with conditional access

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, bots, microsoft-teams

We are using MS botframework as a code bases for our Virtual Assistant.

After struggling with botframework beta 0.3 to make the authentication (for email, calendar,...) work in teams (with magic code), we migrated to boteframework beta 0.4 (as recommanded).

Sadly, we discovered that the new login implementation is not working when Teams is configured for conditional access (related to known Teams issue regarding tabs and conditional access).

I don't see any solution to work around this issue as I was not able to make the authentication work correctly with previous version and has not solution with the new version.

Any ideas? I'm open to try many things :'(

EDIT:
Login is not working:

- Popup opens to token.botframework.com
- redirection to auth page is done
- login is done on the third party
- going back to token.botframework.com
- popup trying to load 'teams' page to send the verification code.
- trying forbiden as my device does not respect the conditional access policy
- this is due to teams not sending context when opening a website into its iframe.

Comment: Are you trying [Virtual Assistant Template Sample Code](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions.git)?

Comment: Yes, in its version beta 0.4

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT do you have any int or other questions?

Comment: Can you explain (or link to other issues) what about Teams login isn't working? 'xyz isn't working' can be any number of things?